# wget not getting the same image as browser

Tags: http, wget

I am trying to download an image from this link using wget, however, the downloaded image is not the same as the one that shows up in Chrome

I have tried setting user-agent and other options, but they didn't work.

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --header="Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" https://www.jcrew.com/s7-img-facade/G4266_KL8984\?$pdp_enlarge$
```

What else can I try?

Edit:
The solution was to escape the $ characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enclose your URL in quotes and/or escape "$" and "\" chars

Remember, double quotes allows interpolation, compare results:

`echo '$RANDOM'`

and

`echo "$RANDOM"`

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work. I keep getting 
ERROR 500: Internal Server Error

Comment: Actually, escaping the dollar sign and not enclosing the url in quotes worked. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Double quotes allows interpolation, compare results: `echo '$RANDOM'` and `echo "$RANDOM"`